# Emulate softkey BACK button

Tags: android, button, stub, emulation

i'm working on a small system overlay and i want to replace my Nexus4 softkeys with it.
Got the home and recend apps thing working but i'm strugglin with the implementation of the back key. Searched like a gold digger but seems i can't find the right answer.

Looks like there is a way to use the IWindowManager but dont't know if it still works?!

**The WindowManager capable of injecting keyStrokes.**

```
final IWindowManager windowManager = IWindowManager.Stub
.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window")); 

import android.os.ServiceManager;  
import android.view.IWindowManager; 

The import android.view.IWindowManager cannot be resolved
The import android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved
```

Also i tried to use the `ActivityManager` to get the `topActivity` but i cant use finish() to go back in the stack.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
// get the info from the currently running task
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
Log.d("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::" + 
taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().finish();
```

Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: I am also searching for same functionality with no luck. I also want the home and recent app button. Can u please tell me where to start?